# How do you use or operators in python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def members_ID():
meme = False
membersID = str(input("enter members ID"))
while (meme) == False:
    meme = True
    if len(membersID) == 4:
        if not (membersID)[0] == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9":
            meme = False
        if not (membersID)[1] == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9":
            meme = False
        if not (membersID)[2] == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9":
            meme = False
        if not (membersID)[3] == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9":
            meme = False

    else:
        meme = False
        print("members ID must be in the format 1111")
        membersID = str(input("enter members ID"))
if meme == True:
    print(membersID)
elif (meme) == False:
    print("members ID must be in the format 1111")
```

if it is not four it works but if it is then the program will come to a halt and not work?

It may have something to do with the `or` operators as when I take them out and enter the required info with 4 digits then it works.

```
def members_ID():
        meme = False
        membersID = str(input("enter members ID"))
        while (meme) == False:
            meme = True
            if len(membersID) == 4:
                if not (membersID)[0] == "0":
                    meme = False
                if not (membersID)[1] == "0":
                    meme = False
                if not (membersID)[2] == "0":
                    meme = False
                if not (membersID)[3] == "0":
                     meme = False

            else:
            meme = False
            print("members ID must be in the format 1111")
            membersID = str(input("enter members ID"))
    if meme == True:
        print(membersID)
    elif (meme) == False:
        print("members ID must be in the format 1111")
```

But not if the information entered is wrong. E.g., `ssss` will make the program stop working but `0000` will (if `0000` is the info required)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `or` in this way. The following:

```
not (membersID)[0] == "0" or "1"
```

is `true` whenever either `not membersID[0] == "0"` or the string `"1"` is non-empty, which it always is. Hence, the `if` statement is always `true`.

What you intended should be written as:

```
not (membersID[0] == "0" or membersID[0] == "1" or membersID[0] == "2") # etc. for 3..9
```

To avoid repeating yourself that much, you can make it this:

```
membersID[0] not in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

Comment: You beat me to it :) I like that you added an example of how to refactor his code into working.

Comment: Thank you I will definitely use this, I need it for my course work prep, prep.

Answer (score 0):

The `or`-operator is between *two* statements or clauses, and returns the first part that is not None, False or equivalent (such as empty strings, lists etc.)

See this example:

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'

print(a == 'b' or 'a')
# 'a'
print(a == 'a' or 'b')
# True
```

First, it prints out the value 'a' because `a == 'b'` is False, and 'a' is not empty, False or None.

Second, it prints out the value `True` because `a == 'a'` is True.

This is convenient if you want a value to be default if None:

```
x = some_variable or 5
```

Here, `x` will be 5 when `some_variable` is None, False (or empty).

So in your chain:

if not (membersID)[0] == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9":
       meme = False

I would expect `meme = False` to run in every situation, because if you relabel it as:

```
a = not (membersID)[0] == "0"
b = "1"
c = "2"
#...
```

Then your if-statement would be

```
if a or b or c  # or d ...
    meme = False
```

Only the first clause, `a` will ever have the chance of not being True.

In other words, doing `if something` will be True if `something` is something that has value:

```
if "2":
    print('This is a tautology')
```

Also, if **not any** of the clauses in a chain of `or`s is resolved as True, it will return the last clause:

```
x = None or False or None
print(x is None)
# True
print(type(x))
# NoneType
x = None or False
print(x)
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my completed awnser based on Thijs van dien's awnser.
(thanks)

```
def members_ID():
    meme = False
    membersID = input("enter members ID")
    while (meme) == False:
        meme = True
        if len(membersID) == 4:
            if membersID[0] not in ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
                meme = False
            if membersID[1] not in ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
                meme = False
            if membersID[2] not in ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
                meme = False
            if membersID[3] not in ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
                meme = False
            if meme == True:
                print(membersID)
            elif meme == False:
                print("enter in the format 1111")
                membersID = input("enter members ID")

        else:
            meme = False
            print("members ID must be in the format 1111")
            membersID = input("enter members ID")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
membersID = str(input("enter members ID"))
```

input() already returns a string. In this line, you are trying to convert a string to a string when you enter a string. Therefore, it throws an error. Correct it to:

```
membersID = input("enter members ID")
```

Comment: thank you but this , unfortunately, does not fix the problem I am having as it still stops if a string with four letters (or numbers) is entered.

Comment: I think I figured out.
     if not (membersID)[0] == "0" or "1" or "2" or "3" or "4" or "5" or "6" or "7" or "8" or "9":

This is not how you check if there is a number in a char. Do these 2 steps:
1. Check if the char is in the string "0123456789" instead of comparing like that
2. Put the comparison in a separate function to not clutter your code

Your code does not work, because it will convert the right expression into (True or True or ... or True). And the left expression will convert to (not True), because it is not (not null). Therefore, meme == False, and the cycle does not quit.

Comment: `str(str(str(str(str("whatever")))))` works perfectly fine.